# WCF Service not showing in Connected Services node in .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf

I have a project that consumes a number of WCF services from an external solution.

When the project was a .NET4.8 project, these WCF services would sit in the Connected Services node. However, since upgrading the project to .NET6, the WCF services show in the solution explorer within Visual Studio in a folder in the tree called Connected Services and not in the Connected Services node.

I'm just wondering if there is something I can do to return these services so that they sit in the node?

Comment: I believe WCF isn't supported in .NET 6. perhaps that is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

The way .NET Framework and .NET add references to wcf services are inconsistent.
But this shouldn't affect adding the WCF service reference, so I don't think a change is needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022